# Error converting video with ffmpeg NReco wrapper library

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, converters

I'm using NReco.VideoConverter for a video converting application. Now I'm trying to replace the audio in the source video for an mp3 track. I'm using this snippet from the official site: http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx but I receiving this error:

audio.mp3: Invalid data found when processing input (exit code: 1)

```
var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.ConvertMedia("video.mp4", null, "output_video.mp4", null, new ConvertSettings() {
  AudioCodec = "copy", VideoCodec = "copy",
  CustomInputArgs = String.Format(" -i \"{0}\" ", "audio.mp3"),
  CustomOutputArgs = " -map 0 -map 1",
});
```

I tried with different audio files but still the same scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this issue. In order to replace the audio in the source video those lines was needed:

```
CustomInputArgs = string.Format(" -i \"{0}\"", audioPath);
CustomOutputArgs = string.Format(" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need to change

```
CustomOutputArgs = " -map 0 -map 1"
```

to

```
CustomOutputArgs = " -map 0:v -map 1:a"
```

Also, you are replacing `audio.mp3` with the actual name of your MP3, right? The error message suggests you aren't.